# Given an even number $\ n\ $ of points in $\mathbb{R}^2,\ $ does there exist a (unique?) polynomial of degree $n-1$ which goes through all the points?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

> Given $\ n\ $ points (where $\ n\ $ is even), $\ (x_1,y_1) ,\ (x_2,y_2),\ \ldots,\ (x_n,y_n),\
>  $ all in $\ \mathbb{R}^2,\ $ with $\ x_k \neq x_j\ $ if $\ k\neq j.$
>
> Then there exists a **real** polynomial $\ p(x)\ $ with degree $\ n-1\ $
> such that $\ p(x_i) = y_i\ $ for all $\ i\in\ \{ 1,2,\ldots, n\}.$

Is this above proposition true? Is the polynomial unique? And is this part of a broader, well-known theorem?

Comment: I am confused and feel dumb.  If I give, say, $4$ distinct points on the $x$-axis (so all $y_i=0$), this says there should be a cubic going through all $4$ of them.  How can a cubic have more than $3$ roots?

Comment: @Randall you're not dumb. You're comment is correct and is what principal-ideal-domain said in his answer...

Comment: OK, I see, nevermind.  I thought the highlighted statement was asserted to be true, but I see that you are asking whether or not it is true.

Answer (score 3):

It's false, but it's almost true. The polynomial can also be of smaller degree. So there is exactly one polynomial of degree at most $n-1$ such that $p(x_i)=y_i$ for all $i \in \{1,\dots,n\}$.

For example if all $y_i=0$ the polynomial is constant $0$ and hence of degree $-\infty$.

**Proof:**

Let $V$ be the vector space of dimension $n$ of polynomials of at most degree $n-1$. For distinct real numbers $x_1,\dots,x_n$ we define the map
$$\varphi:V \to \mathbb R^n, \quad \varphi(f):= (f(x_1),\dots,f(x_n)).$$
This map is clearly linear. Its kernel is trivial, because every element of the kernel must be a multiple of
$$(x-x_1)\cdots(x-x_n)$$
so at least of degree $n$ or the zero polynomial. Hence $\varphi$ is an isomorphism. This proves both: Existence ($\varphi$ is surjective) and uniqueness ($\varphi$ is injective)!

Comment: How can you prove this? With Lagrange or Newton formulas?

Comment: @AdamRubinson You can construct the polynomial using the methods suggested by jjagmath.

Comment: @AdamRubinson Do you wanna see the proof of the existence or the uniqueness?

Comment: yes, definitely. Both if possible. This feels like some linear algebra.

Comment: @AdamRubinson You can find two here: [Interpolating Polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation)

Comment: @AdamRubinson So both? I can write down a proof, but give me a few minutes.

Comment: @AdamRubinson There you have your proof ;-)

Comment: Wow, this is the first time I've ever really understood this result.  It's so simple.

Comment: @Randall And it works over every field, not just $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the proposition is true. You can construct such polynomial using [Lagrange's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial) or [Newton's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_polynomial) formulas. Also, the polynomial is unique. See [Interpolating polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation)

Edit: As @principal-ideal-domain observed, it should read "... with degree of **at most** $n-1$ ..."

Comment: Ah, I've heard of Lagrange polynomials in passing, but never really studied them before. Thanks.

Comment: It's not true, but almost (see my answer).

Comment: You are right, it should be of degree *at most* $n-1$.

Comment: Please adjust your answer to include this "at most" thing so that I can accept it...